# Tourist maps online for Japan?

Tags: online-resources, japan, hiking, maps

Are there any Japan tourist/hiking maps with marked trails and POIs online?

E. g. here is a [tourist map like that for my country](http://mapy.cz/s/8yom). Is there something like that for Japan?

I know just about some OSM renders (hikebike, 4umaps) but I don't know how complete the coverage of Japan is. 
[This is what I have found so far](http://www.mapion.co.jp/m/36.69497111_137.86510306_7/).

If there is no a tourist map of all the Japan are there any maps at least of some areas?

Comment: Have you tried [OpenStreetMap](http://www.openstreetmap.org/)? It has decent coverage and I use it occasionally (that is, applications which use its data) when travelling. There's at least a few Android applications with offline maps (probably for other platforms too), most of which use OSM data since it's free.

Comment: For outdoor activities, see also [Outdoors.SE].

Comment: Yes, I mention OpenStreetMap by OSM with best renders hikebike, 4umaps and opencycle maps for detail view. But unfortunately it is difficult for orientation in smaller scales because there are not many labels there and may not contain all important tracks in large scale .

Comment: Japan is about 10 years behind when it comes to the web in general. Many cities and/or prefectures will have individual pages for trails in their area, but there is very little in the way of consolidated online information. You are better off finding paper pamphlets in mountainous areas. If you limit the scope of your question to specific regions, you may have more luck.

Answer (score 2):

As for maps, you can always make use of OpenStreetMaps or GoogleMaps. Given that you have mobile internet with you.

Most public campsites and trails have map signboards and/or pamphlets.

> If there is no a tourist map of all the Japan are there any maps at
>   least of some areas?

If you happen to live in Tokyo, you can grab a map of Tokyo and a tourist brochure (containing very nifty tips of all the cool places to visit) in the [Tokyo Metropolitan Government Building](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tokyo_Metropolitan_Government_Building).